# Regular expression validate strong password

Tags: regex, validation

I am searching a regular expression for my password.
I need:
First character: letter (upper o lower)
Letters: minimun 1 lower and 1 upper
Not rare caracters
Minimun 8 caracters, max 30

I have:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\W).{8,30}$
```

But i have a problem...

I need write a lower or upper more than first one.
Any idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your regex seems pretty fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems pretty fine for me, but you can simplify a bit:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,29}$
        The first character is not counted here __^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thats the problem. I need to count the first character in the expresssion.

Comment: @Fronesis: Sorry, I don't get you. My regex only accept strings that are from 8 to 30 character long.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it as a single regex.  There's no need to do it in a single regex, and it will be easier to change the rules, and be much easier to read, if you just use multiple if statements.

If you were doing this in Perl, for example, you'd just do

```
my $ok =
    (length($pw) >= 8) &&
    (length($pw) <= 30) &&
    ($pw =~ /[a-z]/) &&  # Has at least one lowercase char
    ($pw =~ /[A-Z]/) &&  # Has at least one uppercase char
    ($pw =~ /^[A-Za-z]); # First character is a letter, either upper or lower.
 ;
```

(I didn't address "not rare character" because I'm not sure what that means.)

That is far easier to read later on when you have to maintain the code in the future.